# Input[type ="button"] sprite hover with transition problems

Tags: css, button, css-transitions, sprite

I would like to know, how you can add a transition when I hover my button. I have made it as a sprite. with two separate images I can make the transition... Is there a good way to make this happen so I save a server request using a sprite.

```
.udfyld_data input[type="button"] { 
    background:url(../../images/kurv/til-betaling-knap.png) no-repeat; 
    width:192px; 
    height:37px;
    border:0;  
    cursor:pointer;
}

.udfyld_data input[type="button"]:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -37px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css3 `transition` property

```
transition: [duration] [property] [timing-function]
```

So your code will be like this:

```
.udfyld_data input[type="button"] { 
    .....
    transition: 1s background linear;
    /*For browser compatibility*/
    -moz-transition: 1s background linear;
    -webkit-transition: 1s background linear;
}
```

**UPDATED**

Use `div` instead of `input` button

**HTML**: `<div class="button"><span></span></div>`

I added a span for some hack

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GW7z6/2/)**

Comment: The suggested code to add does not work. Do I have to activate the transition for the CSS-document?

Comment: No, there is no need for activation. Just add the `transition` property .. Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3k3E7/36/)**

Comment: It looks really weird, it makes a weird turn-over to the next image:/ Maybe you can't make a transition when you have made a sprite. My goal is, when hover to make a fading transition, like you could with colors. Is that possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MikkelMadsen/GW7z6/1/

Some nice fading transition would be nice.

Comment: I can make a hack on it but we will use `div` instead of input tag. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/GW7z6/2/) is the result.